# Traversal of n-dimensional array via a higher-order method

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

Here's an extension method `each` which can be used to apply an `Action<int, int, T>` to every element and it's corresponding indices of a two-dimensional array:

```
static public void each<T>(this T[,] a, Action<int, int, T> proc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
            proc(i, j, a[i, j]);
}
```

Example usage:

```
var arr = new int[3, 3];

arr.each((x, y, val) => arr[x, y] = x + y);

arr.each((x, y, val) => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", x, y, val));
```

Is it possible to write a version of `each` which can work on arrays of any rank?

Comment: The approach that `Func` and `Action` take is to provide a ton of overloads.  If you get beyond a certain level here I'd argue that the problem is too complicated for the overload to be useful.  At a certain point I'd argue that the software will have to dynamically adapt to the number of dimensions you have in your array for it to be understandable.  Also, you should name your method `Each`.  Initial-caps ("PascalCase") is the naming convention for methods in .Net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to specify a generic with an arbitrary number of parameters, so you would have to pass your procedure an array of indices. The easiest way to do this is probably with recursion so here's a recursive way to do it. Since it uses an optional parameter it requires C# 4.0 or higher.

```
static class Arrays
{
    public static void Each<T>(this Array a,
                               Action<int[], T> proc,
                               int[] startAt = null)
    {
        int rank = startAt == null ? 0 : startAt.Length;
        int[] indices = new int[rank + 1];
        if (rank > 0)
            startAt.CopyTo(indices, 0);
        for (int i = a.GetLowerBound(rank); i <= a.GetUpperBound(rank); i++)
        {
            indices[rank] = i;
            if (rank == a.Rank - 1)
                proc(indices, (T)a.GetValue(indices));
            else
                Each(a, proc, indices);
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
var array = new int[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array.Each<int>((indices, data) => array.SetValue(indices.Sum(), indices));
array.Each<int>((indices, data) =>
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", indices) + ": " + data));
```

Comment: This question came about because I've been messing around with a [library](https://gist.github.com/1375626) for 2D arrays and was wondering if there was a way to avoid duplicating all the code for 3D arrays.

Comment: If you just wanted this for 2D and 3D arrays, it would probably be easier to hand-code it. If you wanted it for arbitrary sizes up to a fixed dimension, generating the code might be better (as this code is fairly inefficient).